# Android Compose custom keyboard soft input way

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want do this UI
see video
I think I have to optatoins

1. implement custom keyboard
2. create view and show if current focus
   on specific edit text

**I want know about this app what was implemented and what is the best way for do that**
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Like you said, it's just showing a view/component when focus changes.

Comment: great some edit text must not showing keyboard and show view